# Downloading Terraform onto linux OCI VM

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-kernel, terraform

*I am currently trying to play around with some tf scripting in an OCI compartment I have access to.*
**My current position is:**

- I have successfully spun up a VM through the OCI console running
  Linux 8 on it.
- I have also downloaded OCI CLI successfully.
- I have Downloaded Terraform, and unzipped the file to get the **terraform** binary
  Now i understand that  i need to move the binary into an 'absolute path'? This is where i am getting confused do i simply append the directory where the binary is held to the end of the path shown in this image? I attempt to make an edit to the path but the text appears at the bottom of the page. This is leading my to think i cannot alter the path this way?
  [image: h]

Is there an easier way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Just run "mv terraform /usr/local/bin"

Comment: Just tried that only to get 'permission denied'. Are there limitations to using tf on a vm?

Comment: sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Thank you so much mate it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin
```

Should resolve your issue with sudo overcoming any issues you may have with permissions